# Bad Block Error: Insufficient balance to pay for gas

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, geth-debugging

I was syncing on `full` mode on my Ubuntu OS but when I was approaching the nearest latest block, I was shown this error:

```
########## BAD BLOCK #########
Chain config: {ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Engine: ethash}

Number: 4977759
Hash: 0xfa2a09bd5687c428597c275d62b1c479e2548e2f783de138f4d986d121c37240


Error: insufficient balance to pay for gas
##############################
```

It's just showing me that over and over. I restarted by Geth, I also used `debug.setHead()` and reset the head way back to 40 or 50 previous blocks and all. I did that twice, but still, nothing happened. Does this mean that the DB is corrupted? Is there any way to fix this cause I was syncing this for days and idk why this happened all of a sudden?

Comment: what version of Geth are you using? I guess it is an outdated version that is not compatible with some hardforks that came later (there were multiple). Please check on https://geth.ethereum.org/

Comment: Hello. It's the latest. 1.7.3.

Comment: try deleting your chaindata folder - on Mac thats `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata` and sync again from scratch.